# Множественный выбор чеков

Tags: java, android

Есть меню и там группа с чекбоксами.Могу пометить один потом меню исчезает .Как сделать ччтоб мог отметить флажком более одного чека

```
 <item android:title="All without group">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_1"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="item_1" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_2"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="item_2" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_3"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="item_3" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в том, что в меню не может быть только одна группа с чекбл, он считает ее главной и не слушает команду `android:checkableBehavior="all"`, а автоматом ставит `android:checkableBehavior="single"`.

---

**НАГЛЯДНЫЙ ПРИМЕР**

красным выделены группы с порядком

- I - `android:checkableBehavior="single"`
- II - `android:checkableBehavior="all"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
           android:id="@+id/..."
           android:title="@string/..." /> //добавь что-нить для теста 

    </group>

<item android:title="All group">

    <menu>

        <group
            android:checkableBehavior="all">

            <item
               android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_1"
               android:title="item_1" />

            <item
               android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_2"
               android:title="item_2" />

            <item
               android:id="@+id/nongroup_checkable_item_3"
               android:title="item_3" />

        </group>

    </menu>

</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Не паботает я и сам так делал ))

Comment: @elik ну, а как я должен был понять, что Вы это пробовали?)))

Comment: Я думал ты чувствуешь моё сердце (((( не пиши мне больше

Comment: @elik жаль, а я ведь знаю почему не работает :D

Comment: Бог простил и я прощу)говори)))))

Comment: @elik все дело в том, что в меню не может быть только одна группа с чекбл, он считает ее главной и не слушает команду android:checkableBehavior="all".

Comment: @elik обновил ответ кардинально, должно сработать